# Viewing page headers in Firebug

Tags: firebug

How can I view the page headers sent by the current page I'm viewing in Firebug ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, so long as Firebug is open on the net or console tabs when loading the page.

They will appear in either one of these tabs (though you may need to reload if they were not enabled/open).

Comment: You often need to reload the page in the net tab to see the headers.

Comment: Why do we need to re-fresh the page with `net` tab opened? It's extremely user unfriendly

Comment: @Pacerier - Why? Because no data is collected if the tab is closed. Collecting the data is memory and processor intensive, so shouldn't be done unless required.