# Cakephp Form Labels Encoding Utf8

Tags: forms, cakephp, utf-8, character-encoding

In my php application since the beginning that i set everything with utf8 to avoid future problems. I set my database:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'aquitex',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'aquitex',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

}

The file core.php:

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

And the default layout of the views:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
```

However, i'm still having problems in some elements like labels of forms.

In my index.ctp file, this line:

```
echo $this->Html->link("Segurança", array('controller' => 'Posts','action'=> 'add'), array( 'class' => 'button'));
```

works perfectly and there's no problem with the 'ç' character.

But in forms, like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('Nome Produto');
echo $this->Form->input(utf8_encode("Código Produto"));
echo $this->Form->input("Versão");
echo $this->Form->input('Data');
//echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->end('Criar Ficha');
```

there's no way i can get the words on the labels of the form with 'ó" or 'ç' characters showing properly. As you can see i even tried the utf8encode() in one of them.

Any hints? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to use `utf8_encode()` in your views.
you simply forgot to save the view file properly.
save it as "utf8 without bom" and you will be fine.

files that do not contain any special utf8 char can still stay as ansi (since there is no difference between them then).
but every file that does contain such a character you need to save as utf8 (even controllers and models if you plan on using utf8 characters there for error messages etc).

PS: in general it is wiser to use english and to translate it via PO file into your language.
this way you can leave the files as they are and you are more flexible (you can add new languages on the fly just by creating a new PO file then).

**EDIT**
After figuring out together that your inputs() use utf8 chars, I will need to update:

It is wise to use "underscore_field_names" for your db fields (and therefore your input fields) - and in English:

```
echo $this->Form->input("version"));
```

you can easily translate them via PO file afterwards or specifying the label:

```
echo $this->Form->input("version", array('label' => 'Versão'));
```

but the first way is recommended to keep it dry.

Comment: Hello Mark, it's already in utf8 without bom, i converted the files in notepad++.

Comment: careful: maybe by accident you converted those chars twice? also check your resulting html view via Firefox and Firebug. What is the content-type it is sent with? Maybe your apache setting overwrites the cake one and returns a non-ut8 file. this will also destroy the output.

Comment: About the Model and Controller files, i can't convert them to utf8 without bom. I do it with notepad++, but after i close the file and reopen it on the notepad++, ih the encoding menu it appears again "Ansi".

About the result html, i have in the head section the usual line:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

but yes, in the form that is created, it appears to:
<form action="/aquitex/fichas/index" id="FichaIndexForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>

could it be the problem?

Comment: a) i already told you that converting files that do not have any utf8 chars is pointless (since there is no difference it will always fall back to ansi again)  b) the headers are more important than your markup. therefore you need to check the header via firebug as I pointed out in the previous comment.

Comment: a) Ok, understood, i thought even in that cases they will appear as utf8.
b) well, looking at the head section in the firebug i have the same:
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
Is this section you are talking about right? I mean, i have a div named "header", but that's already on the body of the document.

Comment: no, the header is what you cannot see via browser source. what you are talking about is the dom HEAD section of the html doc. difference.

Comment: Sorry, but you are confusing me. I cannot see in the browser source the head you are talking about? But then how can i see it with the firebug, it it's not the one i was talking about i don't know very well how i should look for him.

I looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156079/viewing-page-headers-in-firebug to try discover, but when i refresh page with firebug open in the console nothing appears :/

Comment: Oh wait, i'm getting it, it's in the net separator. It's this what you were talking about:

Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 7034
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date Fri, 23 Nov 2012 11:06:52 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Server Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.5

Comment: ok,so it seems it is still your file. probably its corrupt because you converted it wrong. try to set up a clean file and dont convert anything, but simply "save as utf8".

Comment: Ok, uf8 or utf8 without bom?

Comment: Not working with either options. Mark could it be really the file? I mean, as i stated in the main post, i'm just having problems with some elements, like the labels of the form, but with other elements the file doesn't have problems in showing the characters correctly.

Comment: ah of course you! you are using the input() wrong. See the documentation. the first param is the database field (lowercase and better ansi only!): "first_name" etc. As I mentioned before. always use english and translate it via po file. clean and simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, it was that! Just didn't understand the part of the po file. never heard of that.

Comment: Should i mark your first answer as the correct one? Or since it was figured out in a comment i should leave as it is?

Answer (score 0):

App.encoding just tells Cake to send data in UTF8. If you're using MySQL, make sure the database itself is set to utf8_general_ci collation.