# $_POST is null in this code, what could be wrong here?

Tags: php, mysql, post

HTML file

```
<form method="post" name="mysearch" action="/abc/search.php" onSubmit="return ch_search()">
    <div class="statea">Search</div>
      <div class="select_a">
        <label for="text2"></label>
        <input type="text" name="skey" id="text2" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = 'Search';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search') this.value = '';" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="select_a">
        <label for="text2"></label>
       <select name="skid[]" id="sele3" multiple="multiple">
                      <? echo $kalist;?>
                    </select>
        </div>
      <div class="select_a">
        <label for="text2"></label>
        <input type="text" name="scity" id="text2" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = 'City';" onfocus="if(this.value=='City') this.value = '';" /><span class="hnt">(Comma Seperated)</span>
      </div>
      <div class="select_a">
        <select name="s_state[]" id="sel3" multiple="multiple">
          <? echo $states;?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="select_a">
        <label for="text2"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="ssubmit" id="text2" value="Search"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

PHP file -

```
if(isset($_POST['ssubmit']))
{
 my code here
 }
```

I tried 
    print_r($_POST); var_dump($_POST);
and everything is coming null.
Its running fine on my local machine but its giving no values in $_POST when uploaded on 
main server.
What is wrong in this code of mine??

EDIT : when iam checking headers in firefox firebug panel then its showing posted data then why cant i see it via php script????

Comment: what does `ch_search()` do?

Comment: what is returning onSubmit="return ch_search()"

Comment: "Its running fine on my local machine but its giving no values in $_POST when uploaded on main server. What is wrong in this code of mine??" Maybe something is wrong with the server?

Comment: `text2` Id should be unique to all the text field...

Comment: Suggestion : Dont use multiple ids with same value in your html `id="text2" `

Comment: this is definetively a JS fail, and not php

Comment: ch_search is just a javascript function that checks whther values are filled or not...that's it.

Comment: @w3developer : and in that you are using getElementById ??? Post that code here i guess problem is in js

Comment: dump question but... have you included the JS file correctly? check the path and if the js file is actually returning any value

Comment: i checked with error console and there is no JS error shown PLUS there are other scripts that are running fine on this server..its just this new project's scripts that are creating this problem

Comment: Comment out all JS and test one at a time (re-insert one at a time), see which one is giving you the problem. Process of elimination usually works.

Comment: check the headers sent to server.

Comment: i ran this code without calling this js function and problem still persist.

Comment: how can i check headers sent to server..plz suggest lvil

Comment: @w3developer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156079/viewing-page-headers-in-firebug

Comment: when iam checking headers in firefox then its showing posted data then why cant i see it via php script????

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem - it was all because of wrong re-write rule in .htaccess.

Rewrite rule was sending this to a new link altogether and thats why all $_POST values were null.

I used -
    RewriteRule ^.*$ abc.xyz.com/header.php [L]

where else it should be - 
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /header.php [L]

It solved all my problems.

Thanks all for your help though :)